# Why does AWS Glue generate multiple json files?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am busy with a POC (using AWS Glue) to pull data from a RDS AWS Postgresql table and I want to generate a JSON file.

I am using the following script, but it keeps on generating multiple files with 5 rows in each file. How do I get it to generate 1 file only?

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "temp-crawlerdb-xxxxx", table_name = "taxservice__3fa3bf8633994e1a827498190adbe56a_contingencyrunningtotal", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "temp-crawlerdb-xxxxx", table_name = "taxservice__3fa3bf8633994e1a827498190adbe56a_contingencyrunningtotal", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("stake", "decimal(18,6)", "stake", "decimal(18,6)"), ("branchid", "long", "branchid", "long"), ("winningstake", "decimal(18,6)", "winningstake", "decimal(18,6)"), ("grossrevenue", "decimal(18,6)", "grossrevenue", "decimal(18,6)"), ("vatrate", "decimal(18,6)", "vatrate", "decimal(18,6)"), ("tmstamp", "timestamp", "tmstamp", "timestamp"), ("usrid", "string", "usrid", "string"), ("contingencyexternalreference", "string", "contingencyexternalreference", "string"), ("winnings", "decimal(18,6)", "winnings", "decimal(18,6)"), ("ggrtaxrate", "decimal(18,6)", "ggrtaxrate", "decimal(18,6)"), ("taxpayable", "decimal(18,6)", "taxpayable", "decimal(18,6)"), ("vatpayable", "decimal(18,6)", "vatpayable", "decimal(18,6)")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("stake", "decimal(18,6)", "stake", "decimal(18,6)"), ("branchid", "long", "branchid", "long"), ("winningstake", "decimal(18,6)", "winningstake", "decimal(18,6)"), ("grossrevenue", "decimal(18,6)", "grossrevenue", "decimal(18,6)"), ("vatrate", "decimal(18,6)", "vatrate", "decimal(18,6)"), ("tmstamp", "timestamp", "tmstamp", "timestamp"), ("usrid", "string", "usrid", "string"), ("contingencyexternalreference", "string", "contingencyexternalreference", "string"), ("winnings", "decimal(18,6)", "winnings", "decimal(18,6)"), ("ggrtaxrate", "decimal(18,6)", "ggrtaxrate", "decimal(18,6)"), ("taxpayable", "decimal(18,6)", "taxpayable", "decimal(18,6)"), ("vatpayable", "decimal(18,6)", "vatpayable", "decimal(18,6)")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://tax-service-xxxxx"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
## @return: datasink2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://tax-service-xxxxx"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Before the Apply Mapping, do this:

```
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

# Convert to a dataframe and partition based on "partition_col"
partitioned_dataframe = datasource0.toDF().repartition(1)

# Convert back to a DynamicFrame for further processing.
partitioned_dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(partitioned_dataframe, glueContext, "partitioned_df")
```

Comment: and don't forget the import statement - from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

Comment: the author should make the import part of the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else come across this the above does work but doesn't really explain why. This post covers it in alot more detail.

https://thedataguy.in/aws-glue-custom-output-file-size-and-fixed-number-of-files/

"Why Glue is producing more small files?
If you are processing small chunks of files in Glue, it will read then and convert them into DynamicFrames. Glue is running on top of the Spark. So the dynamic frames will be moved to Partitions in the EMT cluster. And the Glue partition the data evenly among all of the nodes for better performance. Once its processed, all the partitions will be pushing to your target. Each partition will and one file. That’s why we are getting more files."

Comment: The questioner is asking for a way to generate 1 file... you answered the 'why is it happening' for a good answer can you add 'how to resolve' also